# Smooth mouse cursor movements in jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've seen this feature on a lot of high end websites and can't figure out how they're doing this.

If you go to sites, for example https://webvrgame.dunkirkmovie.com  ---- notice how the mouse cursor is very smooth. Not the cursor image itself, but the movement of the cursor is very smooth, almost delayed slightly, and you can even see the trails. It's very subtle but adds a very elegant feel every time you move the cursor around.

Does anyone know how this is achieved? I'm guessing it is done via JS or jQuery coding of some kind. Thanks!